# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ( \arctan\frac{1}{2} + \arctan \frac{1}{2.2^2} +....+ \arctan \frac {1}{2n^2})$

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Calculate** 
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \arctan\frac{1}{2}  + \arctan \frac{1}{2.2^2} +....+ \arctan \frac {1}{2n^2}\right)$$

**My answer:** i know that $$ \sum_{n=1}^N \arctan \left( \frac{2}{n^2} \right) =\sum_{n=1}^N \arctan (n+1)-\arctan(n-1)$$

as  Im not able  To find the  $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan \frac {1}{2k^2}$

I need  help,,,,,any hints /solution will be aprreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2n^2}=\frac{2}{4n^2}=\frac{2}{1+4n^2-1}=\frac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{1+(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

Therefore,

$$\arctan \left( \frac{1}{2n^2}\right) = \arctan (2n+1) - \arctan(2n-1) $$

Can you perform the telescoping sum now?

Comment: @Messififa Try to use the well known formula : $$\arctan \left( \frac{b-a}{1+ab} \right) = \arctan(b) -\arctan (a)$$

Comment: ya  i  understand that   but  after that  how  can i used  telescope  sum?  can u elaborate  that telescope sum

Comment: @Messififa I suggest you to write for maybe $N=4$ or $N=5$ and you will see.

Comment: @JaideepKhare  i got $\frac{ -\pi}{4}$ is its correct

Comment: @Messififa Well it's almost correct. Correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Just the sign is opposite.